# Lottie animation not behaving as expected

Tags: java, json, android-animation, lottie

I'm using the Lottie library to add animation to my app. I want the animation to play the first half of the animation if some condition is true, and the other half of the animation if the condition is false. below is some code for what I've tried, it seems to work on and off and very buggy, not sure if a lottie issue, or if I'm doing something wrong. thanks for any help!

```
       if (something==true) {
            lottieAnimationView.setMinFrame(0);
            lottieAnimationView.setMaxFrame(28);
            lottieAnimationView.playAnimation();
        } else {
            lottieAnimationView.setMinFrame(28);
            lottieAnimationView.setMaxFrame(70);
            lottieAnimationView.playAnimation();
        }
```

Solution:
 Setting a loop to the animation and using playAnimation(), pauseAnimation() and resumeAnimation()

```
lottieAnimationView.loop(true);
```

Comment: will this code ever reach else statement?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question. my mistake

Comment: just try to log or print out `something` before it enter the statement it will give you an idea why it behaves like this

Comment: Yes, i've done this, I also logged the frames and progress when the animation is played. the frames and progress seem to change and respond to the condition correctly, but sometimes the animation just doesn't play, or plays incorrectly :/

Comment: setting the animation to loop did the trick, silly of me to overlook